# Junit - using for loop to iterate through web element

Tags: junit, webdriver

I am learning using WedDriver. I found this example to demonstrate how to use findElements(by) method.The example used a for loop to find the search box on the web page. Could someone explain how it works and compare it with a regular for loop usage? Thanks for your help. If you could provide me with some tutorial examples by using for loop to iterate through web elements that will be helpful on my understanding. Thanks!

By regular for loop I meant

```
for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
      System.out.println(i);
 } 



for(WebElement ele: elements){
                ele.sendKeys("hexbytes");
            }
```

Here is the code sample from the web:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WD_findElements 
{
    @Test
    public void test_byid() 
    {
      /**
        * Identifying elements by Id
        * Example: Identify search boxes with id and fill them with some text
        */
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        try
        {
            driver.get("http://www.hexbytes.com");

            //Identify the search boxes in the pages
            List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("s"));

            //display number of elements
            System.out.print("Number of search elements: "+ elements.size());

            for(WebElement ele: elements){
                ele.sendKeys("hexbytes");
            }
        }

        finally{
            driver.close();
        }

    }//end of test_by_id method

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop is just another way to iterate over a list. 
It's more or less equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i<=elements.size(); i++){
     WebElement ele = elements.get(i);
     ....
}
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-loop-iterate-a-list-in-java/) you got more examples.

Comment: Hello Stephane. After review the link provided by you. I was able to see how the for loop works. The concepts that helped me are: Java List, Iterator, Java Generic Types vs Parametrized Type. Thanks!